# How to update formset that contains multiple form

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to update an existing formset, but when I try to save the data, there is a validation problem, please help.
my model for that formset is given as:

```py
    class ProductforOrder(models.Model):
        order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        order_product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        order_count=models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

and the form field is given as:

```py
class PoroductforOrderform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductforOrder
        fields = [ f.name for f in ProductforOrder._meta.fields ]
        fields.remove('order')
```

creation of formset given as:

```py
    orderformset = modelformset_factory(ProductforOrder,form=PoroductforOrderform,extra=0)
    formobj = Order.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form=Orderform(instance=formobj)
    formsetobj = ProductforOrder.objects.filter(order=formobj)
    formset = orderformset( queryset=formsetobj)
    print(formset.is_valid())
```

That gives me "False" that I cant update my formset.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your template file I'm going to take a guess that you're individually rendering your form fields instead of just using form. For example in your template you have something like:

```
{% for form in formset %}
    <p>Please input your name {{ form.name }} and age {{ form.age }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

If this is the case, make sure you have `{{ form.id }}` inside your `for form in formset` for loop e.g.:

```
{% for form in formset%}
    <p>Please input your name {{ form.name }} and age {{ form.age }}</p>
    {{ form.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Actually, I am using dynamic formset that user can dynamically add or remove from formset using ajax

Comment: Oh ok. Hope you get it sorted out soon.

Answer (score 0):

`formset.is_valid()` always return false because u didn't provide any data.

Refer to this link:
[formset validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#formset-validation) and [formset in POST method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates)

so in your case,

```
if request.method == "POST":
   formset = orderformset(request.POST, queryset=formsetobj)
   if formset.is_valid():
      # code for valid formset
   else:
      # code for invalid formset
      print(formset.errors) # to check why your formset is invalid
else:
   formset = orderformset(queryset=formsetobj)
```